# How to populate a drop down list from another drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on C#, Visual studio 2012

I have Two Dropdownlists.

In first dropdownlist it shows list of the name of students (from the table [students])..... in second dropdownlist it shows majors (from the table [courses]).

These two will comes from database which contains two tables ( students and courses ).

Suppose when the user select the student from 1st dropdownlist so,in the other dropdownlist it should show related major to that student.

How to do this using asp.net web applications without programming.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean without programming? You could add the onselecteditemchange event and update whatever you need there (to pupulate the second dropdown)

Comment: Without programming? Magic then! Incidentally, magic does not exist.

Comment: That's mean we don't need to add code. I know there is a way to do it but I forgot it. May be adding a query.

Answer (score 4):

I think you meant to say **no code behind** instead of **without programming**.

You can use SQL DataSources.

[image]

### Student Table

```
StudentId | StudentName
----------+-------------
     1    |  Jon
     2    |  Marry
```

### Course

```
CourseId | CourseName | StudentId
---------+------------+----------
     1   |   Physic   |     1
     2   |   Math     |     1
     3   |   Physic   |     2
     4   |   English  |     2
```

### ASPX

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListStudent" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="StudentSqlDataSource"
    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="StudentId" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="StudentSqlDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT StudentId, StudentName FROM [Student]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCourse" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="CourseSqlDataSource" DataTextField="CourseName" 
    DataValueField="CourseId">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="CourseSqlDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Course] WHERE StudentId=@StudentId">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListStudent" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue"
            Name="StudentId" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="1" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

***Note:*** Make sure that **AutoPostBack="True"** for DropDownListStudent